# Chromedriver: ChromeDriver: new Augmenter().augment( driver ) leads to new browser window

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In order to take screen shots we have to augment driver with screen shot feature in following way:

driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);

But when we run this code in Chrome it opens new empty window. How can I avoid it?

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;

public class NewChromeTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com.ua/");
        driver = new Augmenter().augment( driver );
    }
}
```

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Run code above

What is the expected output? 
We should stay in the same browser window.

What do you see instead?
New empty browser (Chrome) window opens

Selenium version: 2.37
OS: Win 7
Browser: Chrome
Browser version: 31.0.1650.63 m!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5ZxB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below two lines to your code

```
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("D:\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: I tried and have following: import java.io.IOException;

public class NewChromeTest {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
driver= new Augmenter().augment(driver);
            File scrFile =(File) ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(directory.getCanonicalFile()+"\\Images\\LatestFailedScreenshot.png"));
```